# Compare nested rows in a tibble and retrieve unique rows only

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `tibble` where each row contains some data. I would like to compare all the rows and retrieve only the **unique** ones.

**reprex:**

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  data = list(mtcars, mtcars, iris, iris)
)

df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 1
#>   data               
#>   <list>             
#> 1 <df[,11] [32 × 11]>
#> 2 <df[,11] [32 × 11]>
#> 3 <df[,5] [150 × 5]> 
#> 4 <df[,5] [150 × 5]>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**expected output:**

```r
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   data               
#>   <list>             
#> 1 <df[,11] [32 × 11]>
#> 2 <df[,5] [150 × 5]>
```

Any ideas? I have tried using `dplyr::distinct()` but it actually does not work in my real example. So, I don't think that is the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `unique`, i.e.,

```
unique(df)
```

such that

```
> unique(df)
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  data               
  <list>             
1 <df[,11] [32 x 11]>
2 <df[,5] [150 x 5]>
```